# Instantiate and reuse instances of objects in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, object, objectdataprovider, instances

I want to instantiate objects in XAML, and reuse these instances. I think it should be simple but I'm stuck, I'm probably missing something obvious.

Say I want to add Cats to different Rooms (Room has an ObservableCollection containing objects of type Cat). In the UserControl.Resources I create ObjectDataProviders:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Cat1" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Cat}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        <System:String>Tom</System:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Cat2" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Cat}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        <System:String>Garfield</System:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Cat3" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Cat}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        <System:String>Furball</System:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

In my UserControl I want to add the Cats to the Rooms:

```
<local:Room x:Name="Room1">
    <local:Room.Cats>

    </local:Room.Cats>
<local:Room>
<local:Room x:Name="Room2">
    <local:Room.Cats>

    </local:Room.Cats>
<local:Room>
```

What is the syntax for adding the Cat instances to the ObservableCollection Room.Cats? For instance I want to add Cat1 and Cat2 to Room1, and Cat2 and Cat3 to Room2. Am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: It *might* be possible to do this by adding `<StaticResource ResourceKey="Cat1" />` to your list of Cats. Since I don't have the possibility to test this at the moment, I'm only adding it as a comment...

Comment: @Heinzi: I tried that, it compiles, but runtime it gives an XamlParseException: Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Cat]'

Comment: I see. The next thing I would try is to (a) create an ObservableCollection in XAML inside `<local:Room.Cats>` (see the "Notes on XAML usage" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) and then (b) replace the `ObjectDataProvider` by a `Cat` (i.e. `<local:Cat Name="Garfield" x:Key="Cat1">`) and then add the StaticResource pointing to the Cat inside your ObservableCollection. This, however, would require your `Cat` class to have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the feedback from Heinzi and Robert Rossney  I came up with the following solution that works with an ObservableCollection that I can access in XAML and code behind:

In code I extended ObservableCollection so I can use it in XAML (this will no longer be necessary in XAML 2009):

```
public class CatObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<Cat> { }
```

In XAML in the UserControl.Resources I instantiate the Cats:

```
<local:Cat x:Key="Tom" Name="Tom"/>
<local:Cat x:Key="Garfield" Name="Garfield"/>
<local:Cat x:Key="Furball" Name="Furball"/>
```

The collections:

```
<local:CatObservableCollection x:Key="Room1Collection">
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Tom"/>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Garfield"/>
</local:CatObservableCollection>
<local:CatObservableCollection x:Key="Room2Collection">
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Garfield"/>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Furball"/>
</local:CatObservableCollection>
```

The Rooms are now defined as follows:

```
<local:Room x:Name="Room1" Cats="{StaticResource Room1Collection}"/>
<local:Room x:Name="Room2" Cats="{StaticResource Room2Collection}"/>
```

Room.Cats is an ObservableCollection<Cat>

Answer (score 7):

Reusing individual instances the way you're trying to do it is tricky.  This is because the way that you generally reference single objects in XAML is with the `StaticResource` markup extension, and you can only use that markup extension to set a property value.

So you can easily set a property of type `Cat` to an instance of a `Cat`:

```
<Room Cat="{StaticResource Cat1}"/>
```

but you can't populate a collection by setting a property.

The answer, surprisingly, is to instantiate your objects directly in XAML instead of wrapping them in `ObjectDataProvider`s.  You still use the `ObjectDataProvider`, but differently:

```
<Window x:Class="ObjectDataProviderDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ObjectDataProviderDemo" 
        xmlns:Collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib" 
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350" 
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Cat x:Key="Tom" Name="Tom"/>
        <local:Cat x:Key="Garfield" Name="Garfield"/>
        <local:Cat x:Key="Furball" Name="Furball"/>
        <Collections:ArrayList x:Key="CatList1">
            <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource Tom}" />
            <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource Garfield}" />
            <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource Furball}" />
        </Collections:ArrayList>
        <Collections:ArrayList x:Key="CatList2">
            <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource Tom}" />
            <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource Furball}" />
        </Collections:ArrayList>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CatTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource CatList1}" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CatTemplate}"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource CatList2}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CatTemplate}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your very specific needs, you to do go for generics. And to use generics declaratively, you have to use [x:TypeArguments Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476(v=vs.110).aspx). TypeArguments directive can be used only with root element. So, you have to now go for loose XAML file. A loose XAML file can be read using `System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(Stream Stream) method`

Cat.cs :

```
using System;

namespace WpfCollection._3840371
{
    public class Cat
    {
        public Cat() { }

        public Cat(String name, String color) { Name = name; Color = color; }

        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Room.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfCollection._3840371
{
    public class Room<T> where T : System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider
    {
        public Room()
        {
            Cats = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<T> Cats { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Window class :

```
namespace WpfCollection._3840371
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Win3840371.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Win3840371 : Window
    {
        public Win3840371()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Room<ObjectDataProvider> kitchenRoom;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"3840371/roomcats.txt", FileMode.Open))
            {
                kitchenRoom = (Room<ObjectDataProvider>)XamlReader.Load(fs);
            }

            foreach (ObjectDataProvider o in kitchenRoom.Cats)
                Debug.WriteLine(((Cat)o.Data).Name + " : " + ((Cat)o.Data).Color);
        }
    }
}
```

So, your .txt file containing XAML code would be :

```
<local:Room 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCollection._3840371;assembly=WpfCollection"
            x:Key="UpperRoom" x:TypeArguments="ObjectDataProvider">
            <local:Room.Cats>
                <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Cat1" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Cat}">
                    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                        <System:String>Tom</System:String>
                        <System:String>Red</System:String>
                    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                </ObjectDataProvider>
                <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Cat2" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Cat}">
                    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                        <System:String>Rubia</System:String>
                        <System:String>Brown</System:String>
                    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                </ObjectDataProvider>
            </local:Room.Cats>
        </local:Room>
```

Comment: Make sure you set Build Action to Content and Copy to output directory property to Always for roomcats.txt.